# Add items from 1 Dictionary to another Dictionary -Swift iOS9

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops, dictionary

1. I have one button named buttonPressed.
2. I have a sodaArray property with sodas in it.
3. I have an empty foodDict property that I later fill with key/value pairs.
4. I have an empty sodaMachineArray property I have to put the sodas in. I append the sodas into it using a function then use another function to assign them key/value pairs to add into the foodDict. I put this all inside 1 function named addSodas().

In the buttonPressed action, 1st I run the function addSodas(). 2nd I fill up the foodDict with different values. I need to append both dictionaries together so that the foodDict has all the sodas in it with it's current values.

The problem I'm having is the addSodas() function has to come first (I have no choice). Since that's first and the foodDict is second, how do I combine both dictionaries?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

//soda values already in the sodaArray
var sodaArray = ["Coke", "Pepsi", "Gingerale"]

//I add the soda values to this empty array(I have no choice)
var sodaMachineArray = [String]()

//This is a food dictionary I want to add the sodas in
var foodDict = [String: AnyObject]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


//Function to add sodas to the foodDict
func addSodas(){

    //Here I append the sodas into the sodaMachineArray
    for soda in self.sodaArray {
        self.sodaMachineArray.append(soda)
    }

    //I take the sodaMachineArray, grab each index, cast it as a String, and use that as the Key for the key/value pair
    for (index, value) in self.sodaMachineArray.enumerate(){
        self.foodDict[String(index)] = value
    }
    print("\nA. \(self.foodDict)\n")
}


//Button
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    self.addSodas()
    print("\nB. \(self.foodDict)\n")

    self.foodDict = ["KFC": "Chicken", "PizzaHut": "Pizza", "McDonalds":"Burger"]
    print("\nD. food and soda key/values should print here: \(self.foodDict)???\n")

    /*I need the final outcome to look like this  
self.foodDict = ["0": Coke, "McDonalds": Burger, "1": Pepsi, "KFC": Chicken, "2": Gingerale, "PizzaHut": Pizza]*/
        }
    }
```

Btw I know I can extend the Dictionary with this method below but it's no use in this situation because the addSodas() func has to come before the foodDict is filled up. This extension works but I can't use it for my scenario.

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func appendThisDictWithKeyValuePairsFromAnotherDict(anotherDict:Dictionary) {
        for (key,value) in anotherDict {
            self.updateValue(value, forKey:key)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The order doesn't matter because the dictionary is unordered anyway.

Comment: I know the dict is unordered. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Issue:**

```
self.foodDict = ["KFC": "Chicken", "PizzaHut": "Pizza", "McDonalds":"Burger"]
```

This line creates the new array and assign those values.

**Solution:**

1. Have an temporary property for holding the key values ["KFC": "Chicken", "PizzaHut": "Pizza", "McDonalds":"Burger"].
2. Iterate and Assign it to FoodDict.

**Example:**

```
//Button
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    self.addSodas()
    print("\nB. \(self.foodDict)\n")

    var tempFoodDict = ["KFC": "Chicken", "PizzaHut": "Pizza", "McDonalds":"Burger"]
    for (key, value) in tempFoodDict {
        self.foodDict[String(key)] = String(value)
    }
    print("\nD. food and soda key/values should print here: \(self.foodDict)???\n")
}
```